# How can I find values in a table on excel or LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: excel, libreoffice-calc

I'am triyng to make a table, where I put person names in the first column and citys in the first row. I am going to choice one person name and one city, I want to know how many of this certain name staying in this certain city. I would like to know if it's possible to make in excell or LibreOffice Calc (I preffer it, because I am on Ubuntu), choice one person name and city name and it return's me how many of them had in the table.

I'm sorry for my english. 
Thank's so much.

Comment: in Excel just use the `=COUNTIF()` function, you'll also need to concatenate the name and city strings into a single string which you can do inside you formula using the `&` operator

Comment: Sorry, I am very newbie in excel, I am using for the first time. Can you give me a example? Where I use this expression? Thanks

Comment: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/two-way-lookup.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the find() function in excel